# SharePoint 2010 user groups - when was user added

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible, in SharePoint 2010 Foundation to find out when a user was added to a particular user group? I have full admin privileges as a site owner. I can find this information out through Audit Log reports but unfortunately I did not turn these on from day one so am looking for another method. I assume that SharePoint must be storing this information somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Powershell, use the ***repadmin*** command. Like below

```
repadmin /showobjmeta dc1 'CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=rivendell,DC=com'
```

For more detail check this [post](http://learn-powershell.net/2013/05/21/find-when-a-user-was-added-or-removed-to-a-domain-group-using-powershell-and-repadmin/)